# Prevent ID 1 from being deleted

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a code that gets the ID of the account and deletes it in the database 
but i need to prevent the **ID 1** from being deleted.

how can i do that ?

```
   <?php

    // connect to the database
    include('dbconn.php');

    // confirm that the 'id' variable has been set

    if (isset($_GET['admin_ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['admin_ID']))
    {
    // get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $id = $_GET['admin_ID'];

    // delete record from database
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_ID = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
    $con->close();

    // redirect user after delete is successful
    header("Location: DeleteAdmin.php");
    }
    else
    // if the 'id' variable isn't set, redirect the user
    {
    header("Location: DeleteAdmin.php");
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: check for the `id`, if one then don't operate the delete query.

Comment: `WHERE admin_ID <> 1`

Comment: You are using if statements in your code, so not sure what more you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `DELETE FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_ID = ? LIMIT 1` to `DELETE FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_ID = ? AND admin_ID != 1`
The `LIMIT 1` is unnecessary assuming you that is the primary id and thus there can never be two with the same id.